# Plot monthly average over multiple years with Xarray

Tags: python, pandas, plot, python-xarray

I have the monthly average of u and v components from the ERA 5 reanalysis. I first calculate de wind direction and speed from the u and v components, and then save those to new variables. I then select a location for which I want to plot the time series of those new variables, this works fine.

What I want to do next is plot the monthly values with each year as a separate line. So the X-value would be jan through dec, y-value the speed (or direction) and each line would be labeled with the year.

My data: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjhLAXJj0C_0t2w1j5TCjzR3g1My?e=IjMFbk

```
dataset = xr.open_dataset("Feb2020.nc")    
                                  
# Create new layer of speed m/s
dataset["speed"] = np.sqrt(np.square(dataset.u10) + np.square(dataset.v10))    
dataset.speed.attrs["units"] = "meter_second"
dataset.speed.interpolate_na(dim='time')

# Create new layer of direction
dataset["direction"] =  270 - (np.arctan2(dataset.v10,dataset.u10)*(180/np.pi))
dataset.direction.attrs["units"] = "degrees"

# Set lat and lon for extraction point
lon_st = 6.25                                                                  
lat_st = -55.00

# Extract timeseries based on lat/lon
monthly_speed = dataset.speed.sel(longitude=lon_st, latitude=lat_st, expver=1, method='nearest')    
monthly_direction = dataset.direction.sel(longitude=lon_st, latitude=lat_st, expver=1, method='nearest') 

#What my data looks like

In[13]: dataset
Out[13]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (expver: 2, latitude: 7, longitude: 17, time: 493)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -57.5 -57.25 -57.0 ... -54.0 -53.75 -53.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 7.0 6.75 6.5 6.25 6.0 5.75 5.5
  * expver     (expver) int32 1 5
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 1979-02-01 ... 2020-01-01
Data variables:
    u10        (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 -3.9958236 ... -2.9505084
    v10        (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 -3.8422172 ... -1.6807995
    speed      (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 5.543396 ... 3.3956716
    direction  (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 406.12274 ... 420.33136
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2020-02-20 12:31:11 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.16.0: /opt/ecmw...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with converting the Xarray Dataset to Pandas Dataframe.
The reason is that you need two - groupby action for year and for month, and Xarray currently supports only one groupby.

```
# convert to dataframe:
df = monthly_speed.reset_coords(drop=True).to_dataframe()
# add year and month indices:
df['month']=df.index.month
df['year']=df.index.year
# groupby month and year then mean:
dfm = df.groupby(['year','month']).mean().unstack().T.droplevel(0)
# plot:
dfm.plot()
```

The plot is not very nice, you could adjust it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It is hard for the community to help you if you do not share the data and anything else to reproduce your issue
2. What you can do is using matplotlib. Code should look like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dataset.time.values, dataset.speed.values, label='Windspeed')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('monthly_wind_speed_mean.png')
```

3. Or you use one of xarray functions which uses matplotlib too:

[Check out Multiple lines from a 2d DataArray
example](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/visualization_gallery.html)

Comment: I added the description of the data in my question so people understood how it was structured. I've now updated with a link to the actual netcdf file.